# Is it possible to set the nodes and edges positions specified by user in Python Graphviz?

Tags: python, charts, graphviz

I'd like to build the following chart (I did it NOT in Graphviz):
[image]

I tried to do it in `Python` Graphviz with the following code:

```
g = Digraph(engine='neato')
g.node('1', label='Very long name', pos='0,0')
g.node('2',label='Another very long name', pos='0,-1')
g.edge('1', '2')

g.node('3','Very long name again', pos='0,-2')
g.edge('2', '3')
g.node('4', 'Another very long name', pos='10,-3')
g.edge('3', '4')

g
```

which outputs the following:
[image]

For controlling the position of nodes I tried to use `neato` engine, but it seems to me, that it does not work properly, so I have no idea how to control the position of nodes and edges in Graphviz, is it possible in principle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rank` attribute to control this in a subgraph of g.

```py
from graphviz import Digraph

g = Digraph()

g.node('1', 'Very long name')
g.node('2', 'Another very long name')
g.node('3', 'Very long name again')
g.node('4', 'Another very long name')

g.edges(['12', '23'])

with g.subgraph() as s:
  s.attr(rank='same')
  s.edge('3', '4')

g
```